# Show some elements from jquery collection of elements

Tags: jquery, collections, element, show-hide

¡Holla pros,

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/D369e/) piece of code, which is partially working. Based on some conditions I want to make visible some of the list elements. Currently only the alert works. I`m not sure what is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) wrong; it's meant to change an attribute of some html element. I was able to get this working by just changing `attr` to `css`, which is the correct way to update css; [link to working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eykanal/BynfT/). You could also consider using classes combined with [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which can make your code easier to manage.